# Wired Connection problem on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: connection, wired

I have installed Ubuntu 14.10, because, as usually, I wanted to see the next Ubuntu version anxiously and without any respect to the LTS version I had prior to the upgrade. Nevertheless, everything was OK until few days ago, when the wired connection suddenly decided to stop working. I was now worried and waited for the daily updates, which were supposed to fix this problem. Alas, after a number of updates, I still can't establish wired connection. The arrows are shown in the network indicator, Ubuntu says it has wired connection, but no internet, no network. ON the other hand, WIFI is working just fine. Could somebody, please, help me? 
Remarks: The IT guy entered the fixed IP address and everything, tried with the automatic option, nothing happened. And it worked just fin few days ago, before one of the updates. I don't understand.

Comment: meto, how do I ping, what's the command? And what is the command to see the content of /etc/network/interfaces? Sorry for bothering.

Comment: This is the response to pinging gogle:PING google.com connect: Network is unreachable

Comment: Interesting, the main server allows me to see all of the network in my company, but wouldn't allow me to access Internet. To make things even more awkward, the server is... on Ubuntu! So, I do have access to the network, I do have access to Internet via WIFI, but the same server wouldn't let me access the Internet via wire.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've had the same problem within virtual! Ubuntu client too. Sometime ubuntu fix the connection suddenly or it works fine if i change the network connection from virtual network connettion options. I dont know It could be a bug for the latest version of Ubuntu.

Ubuntu says it has wired connection, but no internet, no network!
Can you ping to www.google.com from terminal?

You can check the network interfaces from terminal /etc/network/interfaces. If there is a DHCP on the network that you dont need the change anything there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this bug on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1354924